# Limiting JASidePanel Center panel slide

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I am using JASidePanels to create the left menu style but I want to do some particular changes.

The first is that I want the menu to have only 115 px wide. And for that I have found:

```
self.leftFixedWidth = 115;
```

Ok but, I can still slide the center panel to the right and see whats "hidden". Is there a way to fix its maximum position at 115 px? Just like the facebook menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to JASidePanelController.m

find `- (CGFloat)_correctMovement:(CGFloat)movement;` method, replace it with this:

```
- (CGFloat)_correctMovement:(CGFloat)movement {
    CGFloat position = _centerPanelRestingFrame.origin.x + movement;
    if (self.state == JASidePanelCenterVisible) {
        if (self.state != JASidePanelLeftVisible) {
          if (position >= self.leftVisibleWidth) {
            return self.leftVisibleWidth;
          }
        }
        else if ((position > 0.0f && !self.leftPanel) || (position < 0.0f && !self.rightPanel)) {
            return 0.0f;
        }
    } else if (self.state == JASidePanelRightVisible && !self.allowRightOverpan) {
        if ((position + _centerPanelRestingFrame.size.width) < (self.rightPanelContainer.frame.size.width - self.rightVisibleWidth)) {
            return 0.0f;
        } else if (position > self.rightPanelContainer.frame.origin.x) {
            return self.rightPanelContainer.frame.origin.x - _centerPanelRestingFrame.origin.x;
        }
    } else if (self.state == JASidePanelLeftVisible  && !self.allowLeftOverpan) {
        if (position > self.leftVisibleWidth) {
            return 0.0f;
        } else if (position < self.leftPanelContainer.frame.origin.x) {
            return  self.leftPanelContainer.frame.origin.x - _centerPanelRestingFrame.origin.x;
        }
    }
    return movement;
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works but only for the first paning movement. Now I want to keep it like this if I try to move the center panel while the left panel is visible.

Comment: adding 2 more comparisons made it work for me:
`else if (self.leftVisibleWidth + movement > self.leftFixedWidth) {
        return self.leftPanelContainer.frame.origin.x;
    } else if (self.leftVisibleWidth + movement < self.leftPanelContainer.frame.origin.x) {
        return self.leftPanelContainer.frame.origin.x - self.leftFixedWidth;
    }`